# Strip Time Zone from a string using JavaScripty, Moment.js, etc?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetimeoffset

Suppose I have a string like "01/22/2014 2:07:00 PM -08:00".

I want to

- a) Format it in ISO 8601 with time offsets from UTC http://goo.gl/JTfAZq, so it becomes "2014-01-22T14:07:00-08:00"
- b) Strip out time offset part so it becomes "01/22/2014 2:07:00 PM" [and then format it in ISO 8601 so it becomes "2014-01-22T14:07:00"]

Sure I can use JavaScript string functions (and regular expressions), but it seems to be a better approach to use JavaScript Date() object facilities or Moment.js. Neither work, however. Both automatically convert dates to a current system timezone (-05:00 for me), so 2:07 PM becomes 5:07 PM. I found two ways of doing that "strip out time offset then format" task, but both looks ugly and brittle:

```
var mydateTime = "01/22/2014 2:07:00 PM -08:00";

// strip out time offset part using substring() so that Moment.js
// would think time is specified in a current zone
var myNewDateTime1 = moment(mydateTime.substring(0, mydateTime.length - 7)).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")

// or probably even worse trick - strip out time offset part using format
var myNewDateTime2 = moment(mydateTime, "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")
```

I understand that JavaScript Date() object is not designed to preserve a time zone, but doesn't more elegant and stable solution exist for a) and b) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`moment.ParseZone`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/).  It parses the moment AND preserves the time zone offset that was in the string, instead of converting it to the browser's local time zone.

Also, your `myDateTime` variable doesn't match what you were asking about.  If you do indeed already have a full ISO8601 extended with time zone offfset, then it is like this:

```
var m = moment.parseZone("2014-01-22T14:07:00-08:00");
```

Or if it's like you originally, showed, then like this:

```
var m = moment("01/22/2014 2:07:00 PM -08:00",
               "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A Z").parseZone();
```

From there, you can format it however you like:

```
var s = m.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I tried to edit my comment above for too long, so I just deleted it then.

Matt, moment.parseZone does not have a second parameter according to documentation you linked.

Attempting to parse as
    moment.parseZone("01/22/2014 2:07:00 PM -08:00", "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A Z")
or
    moment.parseZone("01/22/2014 2:07:00 PM -08:00");

both return _d: Invalid Date

Comment: You are correct! Nice catch!  Use the syntax in my updated answer instead.  I'll file a bug for the other one.

Comment: "your myDateTime variable doesn't match what you were asking about."
Matt, I modified my post to fix that, thanks.

Comment: perfect answer for a simple straight forward solution. I like this, because it means there is no need to create a new var with a new date with the timezone stripped off. It's so simple!

    moment("2017-03-22T09:07:19.000-0400").parseZone().format('MMM D, YYYY')